# reloadData doesn't do anything when called from a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

**UPDATE:** The problem is kind of resolved. I put everything from my functions class directly into my myView class.... now works like a charm. Don't exactly know why, but it does. Maybe some of you could speculate on that. I'd welcome any help.

**------**

I thought myself at least an advanced programmer before objective-c... I just started coding apps and it went quite ok so far. But now I'm in a bit of pickle. See, I have a UITableView whose data is supposed to update periodically. My app gets its data from a webserver and stores it into an array. so far so good - all that works according to NSLog outputs. The UiTableView EVEN UPDATES when I put the `[myTable updateData]` into a button action. But when it's called out of another method, it does nothing...

My code so far (abbreviated):
myView.h:

```
@interface myView : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    @public
    IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;
}

- (void)reloadMyTable;
- (IBAction)testbtn:(id)sender;

@end
```

myView.m:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section

{
    Model *model=[Model getInstance];
    return [model.ARrecentnews count];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{
    return numberOfSections;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:   (NSInteger)section

{
    return @"Some Headline";
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellID"];
    Model *model=[Model getInstance];
    cell.textLabel.text = [model.ARrecentnews objectAtIndex:([model.ARrecentnews count]-indexPath.row-1)]; //Populating Table in reverse order

    return cell;
}


- (IBAction)testbtn:(id)sender {

    [myTable reloadData];

}


- (void)reloadMyTable {

   [myTable reloadData];

}
```

Comment: How and where do you call `reloadMyTable`? Do you accidentally alloc a new instance of your ViewController class instead of using the one that displays the visible table?

Comment: @Maximilian Rabe please first check that have you given Outlet to you TableView in xib. i mean have you connected myTable to the tableview you have taken in xib file. in .h file

Comment: Have you set the delegate for the 'myTable'. And check what hpp said above.

Comment: I have a Function.h/.m class where I collect functions I use throughout the app. In this class I perform the data collection from the server and once the data got stored in the array it calls the reloadMyTable by: myView *view = [[myView alloc]init]; [view reloadMyTable];

Comment: @hpp: I set the outlets for dataSource and Delegate. Like I said, the function works fine when I press the Button, so I suppose the Outlets are set correctly, right?

Comment: have u taken TableView in .xib file or u are setting its frame dynamically ? if you have taken in xib file then check whether you have given outlet (TableView in xib to myTable object in .h file) or not.

Comment: I created the TableView in my Storyboard (I put a TableView in a ViewController) and outlet DataSource and Delegate of the TableView to ViewController. Also I outlet TableView to myTable via Referencing Outlet.

Comment: you haven't specified IBOutlet in front of UITableVIew *myTable object in your .h file as shown in above code..then how are you able to give the reference ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are calling UI code from the main thread:

```
- (void)reloadMyTable {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [myTable reloadData];
    });
}
```

(I strongly suspect that the code that gets the data from the web server is running in a background thread; if not it should be)...

Comment: How do I find out in what kind of thread it's running? the code that gets the data is in a function that uses `NSURLRequest`

Comment: @MaximilianRabe Did you try this code to see if it solved your issue?

Comment: i did, so far no luck

Answer (score 0):

please first check that have you given Outlet to you TableView in xib. i mean have you connected myTable to the tableview you have taken in xib file. 
in .h file  replace

```
UITableView *myTable;
```

with

```
IBOutlet  UITableView *myTable;
```

and provide the reference.

and add the following line to cellFor RowAtIndexPath:

```
if(cell==nil)
{
cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cellID"];
}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: changed it. still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point in cellForRowAtIndexPath: and when the [mytable reloadData]; is called, check that it is firing the tbaleview's del method. I suspect it is reloading the data but there is no new data to display ? Have you checked the datasource ?

Also, what does your .h file look like now with the changes ? In IB have you linked the tableview's datasource/delegate to your view ?

Answer (score 0):

> In this class I perform the data collection from the server and once the data got stored in the array it calls the reloadMyTable by: `myView *view = [[myView alloc]init]; [view reloadMyTable]`;

From your comment it looks like you create a new instance of your viewController, and then you call your method on that instance. That won't do anything to the displayed tableView.

You have to figure out a way to get the reference to the already existing `myView` instance. How you do that depends on what you do in your code, and it's hard to tell without knowing that.

You could just add a @property to your Function class that saves the viewController. Or you add a completion block that calls reloadData. You could probably use NSNotifications too. 
There are many ways to tell the displaying viewController that it should reload its tableView.

---

PS: Classes in Objective-C should start with a capital letter, i.e. your class should be called MyView. And since that class is a subclass of UIViewController and not a UIView I would call it `MyViewController`. Clarity is important, and I would not expect a UIViewController subclass to be called MyView.